# Make session work with Curl (ZF2)

Tags: php, rest, session, curl, zend-framework2

I'm working with REST in my Zend Framework 2 application. In order to test my rest calls, I use Curl to send REST requests as follows:

```
$client = new Http\Client();
$client->setAdapter(new Http\Client\Adapter\Curl());

$request = new Http\Request();
$request->setUri($url);
$request->setMethod($method);

$response = $client->dispatch($request);
$jsonString = $response->getContent();
```

Everthing works fine except that the Curl requests seem to ignore the session. I need access to the logged-in user in my rest request handling to e.g. make Acl work. When I send REST request using AngularJS, the session actually works. Here's how I set up the session:

```
$storage = new SessionArrayStorage();
$manager = new SessionManager($config, $storage);
$session = new Session('surveylab', $manager);
```

How can I pass the session information to Curl, so I get access to the session in the Curl requests?

Comment: My experiences demonstrated me that web services should not rely on session data. Think of them as ordinary methods: so with curl you send for example email &passwd every time you call your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the cURL options for:

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR
```

look for examples for the cURL usage of them:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Send your login credentials as post to your login url, extract the cookies from the result and send them with the next request. I don't know if your application updates the cookies over time but you should update them if necessary.
Some example code:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://your/url",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Cookie: ' . $cookies . '"'),
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => count($postData),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_string
));
```